# How to design self referencing aggregate in Domain Drive Design

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

Im working on a Task System where a Task can have collection sub-tasks and sub-tasks can have collection of sub-tasks and so on (recursive).

`DOMAIN`

The `task` are given based on `Organizational Chart`

Example Org Chart:

```
Mahdi
---Saeed
------Jaime
------Ahmed
---Tarawneh
------Mae
---Rasheed
```

The upper person on the Org Chart will assign task to the person under him.

Lets say Mahdi will assign task to Saeed named `prepare course materials for IELTS`.

Then Saeed might divide the task into sub-tasks.

```
prepare course materials for IELTS
---issue laptop and equipment (assigned to Jaime)
---prepare the checklist form(assigned to Ahmed)
```

Then in case its really a big task, Jaime might divide it further into sub-tasks.

As per domain experts, its usually under 3levels

Invariants:

- when moving the deadline of task, it should check that it should not exceed the deadline of its parent task
- if the task has sub-tasks, it will base its status on them. (the task will remain pending until there is one sub task that is pending.... the task will be automatically marked as done when all its sub tasks are done)
- each individual task can update their status if they dont have sub tasks

**EDIT**

- I can only update task status that are assigned to me or I assigned to.
- I can only give tasks to staff that are directly under me

Do I have to stick with the `Task` concept or there are concepts that Im still missing like MainTask & SubTask (just an example)?

If I will stick to the `Task` concept, should I load the whole graph or only the direct parent and child?

OR should I just delegate all the work to a Domain Service? which might turn the Task to anemic model?

Comment: What you have here is a business process with a bunch of scenarios, it's not just one business case with one aggregate.  At a quick glance it seems the `Task` concept can also be used as a grouping criteria for other Tasks. You need to identify each business case and the correct aggregate for `Task` in each case and the result of it (the relevant **Event**) then 'chain' them as scenarios. It's not trivial.

Comment: @Daskul what's your question ? How does your domain model look like so far ?

Comment: @MikeSW can you help me spot some more concepts aside from Task? Im thinking since task is always comes directly above, I dont have to load the whole graph. Only the direct parent and child.

Comment: @guillaume31 actually my question is on the title part. I will try elaborate more. Thanks

Comment: @MikeSW what do you mean by chain them as scenarios?

Comment: @Daskul the title seems to refer to the difficulty of modelling an aggregate that references itself, but the question itself looks more like you're asking "plz model my stuff"...

Comment: @guillaume31 yes I think you're right, thank you for pointing that out. I've made some edits to be more specific.

Comment: You would have to stick with the `Task` concept, but the fact is you have a number of business cases and different events. You have to identify the sequences of command->event->command etc, each sequence handling a specific scenario like `Task with no subtasks` , `Task with subtasks` ,`Updating a task status changes parent status` etc. One more thing, `Task` aggregate has only constraints that ensure `Task` invariants, other business rules are part of Domain Services.  I don't have the time to properly think about it, that's why I can give you only some guidelines.

Answer (score 6):

You should review Vaughn Vernon's series on [Effective Aggregate Design](https://vaughnvernon.co/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/DDD_COMMUNITY_ESSAY_AGGREGATES_PART_1.pdf); the problem domain he explores has similarities to what you describe.

> when moving the deadline of task, it should check that it should not exceed the deadline of its parent task

What's the cost to the business if this invariant fails?

If getting the deadlines wrong is an expensive problem that has to be prevented, then you are going to be forced into a design where all of the deadlines of a task graph need to be contained within a single aggregate boundary (because ultimately, all of the writes to a task deadline need to be immediately consistent with the deadline of the root task).

However, this isn't a particularly hard condition to detect after the write occurs.  If you can loosen the restriction -- allow "invalid" deadlines, but implement the ability to detect them and remedy them -- then you've got a lot more flexibility in where you put your boundaries.

The question in your status requirements is similar: if you need the status updates to be immediately consistent, if you need to cascade the write of the status change all the way up the task graph in a single transaction, then all of the task statuses need to be in the same aggregate boundary.

If that's not the case; if it is enough to see that the sub tasks have finished, and update the parent task state in a separate transaction, then you have more flexibility in where you draw the aggregate boundaries.

My guess is that you are going to want to avoid loading the entire task graph for each write.  If all of the tasks are part of the same aggregate, then you can only update one task at a time.  Immediate consistency means more write contention; you need to sit down with the domain experts and make sure that everyone understands which of these is more important to the business.

> - I can only update task status that are assigned to me or I assigned to.
> - I can only give tasks to staff that are directly under me

Again, does this really have value to the business?  Is this really part of your task assignment context, or does the responsibility belong with authorization?

You also need to think about what the book of record is.  If your model is the authority for who reports to whom, then it may make sense to try to enforce an invariant the joins task assignment to the reporting chain.  But if, like most organizations, the reporting chain is decided in the real world, then it doesn't really make sense for the model to be enforcing tight constraints because its copy of the data is stale.

Task assignment is probably similar - some manager is making the decision to delegate some work, and is merely informing the system that is the case.

In these situations, where the real world violates the the business rule, the system should be tracking that, rather than trying to pretend that it can't happen.

Comment: If I will go on eventual consistency path. Then should I delegate the work on a Domain Service? btw I've made an edit on my post I you have the time to review it.